# Make Ubuntu resistant to power failure

Tags: mount, sync, ext4, fsck, initramfs

What would be the steps to take to make Ubuntu resistant to power failure. I expect these to happen at any time e.g. startup, operating and shutdown.

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server and currently I use EXT4 with sync and journaling.

However, when i stress the system with repetitively powercuts, I do see the system fail doing boot and shows a terminal in initramfs where fsck returns error code 4 (Filesystem errors left uncorrected).

The system runs in a remote/isolated environment and thus I can't use the initramfs terminal to fix my system.

Comment: That's two separate questions, if I read it correctly. An APC UPS and `apcupsd` software for question #1. And `fsck -f /` at the root console prompt for question #2. Do you have console access? Do you have access to a DVD drive on the system?

Comment: It's currently not an option to make any HW changes.

Comment: Then there's no way to make it "resistant to power failure". What about fsck, and my other two questions? And if you're doing "repetitive power cuts" you're going to damage something.

Comment: fair enough - let's say more robust then :-)
The system runs remote and thus, using a live disk or something similar is not an option.

Could you clarify why the system would never be completely resistant - what is it that will break eventually and is this because of the OS or filesystem?

Comment: It's unclear... is your system broken right now? Do you have console access?

Comment: No, I'm not in the situation where I have one broken system. Instead I have several remote headless systems all running the same software which I now have a rare opportunity to "upgrade" the software on the system. I'll like to use this oputunity to improve on the stability of the system.

On my desk I have made a small test setup where I use a relay to cut the power randomly from a test system.

Comment: 1) I think that you'd do more harm to a system by randomly forcefully cutting the power, 2) if you've installed such relays at your sites, you'd do much better to follow my first suggestion, and install some APC UPS and `apcupsd` software. Please see my quick answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There is no software solution for power failure -- it's too quick for software to react in a meaningful way, absent a UPS to let the system perform a shutdown.  If you have servers in a rack you don't have physical access to, and the colocation provider doesn't have UPS on those servers, you need to find a way to move your servers.

Comment: @heynnema The setup with relays is a test setup at my desk not one of the actual systems - I'm sorry that I havn't been clear on that part :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

To improve the reliability of your servers, I'd strongly suggest the installation of an APC UPS to cover brown/black outs, and the installation of `apcupsd` software that allows a graceful server shutdown during extended power outages.

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option for me right now - thanks for the input.

Comment: @Morten however... it IS the correct/best answer. You might still accept it even if you can't implement now.

Comment: Fair, guess I didn't formulate my question right then :-)